# making several api calls slows down react native app

Tags: react-native

So I am calling getUserProducts() (to show the updated list) whenever a product is added to the list and whenever a product is deleted from the list. But I've noticed when I add several items to the list through the dropdown, some times the product doesn't show in the list/getUserProducts isn't called (and then if I add another product it'll then show the previous added product) I'm assuming its because I'm calling it every time I add and that's  making it slow? Is there a way I can work around this to optimize it?

```
const App = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<ProductType[] | []>([]);
  const [userProducts, setUserProducts] = useState<ProductType[] | []>([]);
  const [toggleCheckBox, setToggleCheckBox] = useState(false);

  const [value, setValue] = useState(' ');
  const [isFocus, setIsFocus] = useState(false);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const [productId, setProductId] = useState('');
  const [product, setProduct] = useState('');
  const [num, setNum] = useState('');
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState('');

  const submitForm = async () => {
    let body;
    body = {
      product_id: productId,
      product: product,
      num: num,
      amount: amount,
    };

    const response = await postProduct(body);
    if (response == undefined) {
      return;
    }
  };

  const getProducts = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://192.168.1.32:3000/api/products');
      setProducts(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      // handle error
      alert('no');
    }
  };

  const getUserProducts = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        'http://192.168.1.32:3000/api/user_products',
      );
      setUserProducts(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      // handle error
      alert('no');
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getProducts();
    getUserProducts();
    console.log(userProducts);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Provider>
        
        <Dialog visible={visible} onDismiss={() => setVisible(false)}>
          <DialogHeader title="Add to your list" />
          <DialogContent>
            <Dropdown
              style={[styles.dropdown, isFocus && {borderColor: 'blue'}]}
              data={products}
              search
              maxHeight={300}
              labelField="product"
              valueField="num"
              placeholder={!isFocus ? 'Select item' : '...'}
              searchPlaceholder="Search..."
              value={value}
              onFocus={() => setIsFocus(true)}
              onBlur={() => setIsFocus(false)}
              onChange={item => {
                setValue(item.num);
                setProductId(item.product_id);
                setProduct(item.product);
                setNum(item.num);
                setIsFocus(false);
              }}
            />
            <TextInput
              label="quantity"
              variant="standard"
              onChangeText={text => {
                setAmount(text);
                console.log(text);
              }}
            />
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button
              title="Cancel"
              compact
              variant="text"
              onPress={() => setVisible(false)}
            />
            <Button
              title="Add"
              compact
              variant="text"
              onPress={() => {
                setVisible(false);
                submitForm();
                console.log('added');
                getUserProducts();
              }}
            />
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>

        {userProducts.length > 0 ? (
          userProducts.map(userProduct => (
            <ListItem
              title={
                userProduct.product +
                ' x' +
                userProduct.amount +
                '             num: ' +
                userProduct.num
              }
              onPress={async () => {
                await deleteProduct(userProduct.product_id);
                console.log('deleted');
                getUserProducts();
                ToastAndroid.show('Done', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
              }}
              trailing={
                <CheckBox
                  disabled={false}
                  value={toggleCheckBox}
                  onValueChange={newValue => setToggleCheckBox(newValue)}
                />
              }
            />
          ))
        ) : (
          <Text>Nothing in your list yet</Text>
        )}
      </Provider>
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty certain that you aren't experiencing "lag" but race conditions.

See, when you create an item, you call `submitForm()` and `getuserProducts()` and both are async functions. Depending on how long the individual requests take, or how their execution gets scheduled `getuserProducts()` may very well finish before `submitForm()`. The new data then only reaches the server **after** you fetched the (not so) *new* data.

Consider the following code (it's just a simplified version of your app):

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

interface ProductType {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export default function NotWorking() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<ProductType[]>([]);

  const createProduct = async () => {
    await serverCreateProduct(`product: ${products.length}`);
    console.log('product created');
  };

  const getProducts = async () => {
    setProducts(await serverGetProducts());
    console.log('products loaded...');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          createProduct();
          getProducts();
        }}
      >
        Add
      </button>
      <h2>List:</h2>
      <ul>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <li key={String(product.id)}>{product.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

const _userProducts: ProductType[] = [];
async function serverGetProducts() {
  return new Promise<ProductType[]>((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve([..._userProducts]);
    }, 300);
  });
}

async function serverCreateProduct(name: string) {
  return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      _userProducts.push({ id: Math.random(), name });

      resolve();
    }, 500);
  });
}
```

If you execute it, you will see that `getProducts()` finishes before `createProduct()`, so that result cannot include the new data.

You should await both of them, in order to get what you want, for example:

```js
const createProduct = async () => {
  await serverCreateProduct(`product: ${products.length}`);
  console.log('product created');
  setProducts(await serverGetProducts());
  console.log('products loaded');
};

// ...

<button onClick={() => createProduct()}>Add</button>
```

See the code working [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-pdnwa6?file=App.tsx).